# Convert a 1d array index to a 3d array index?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got a int that I want to convert to 3 ints for the index of a 3d array, here's an example of what I'm on about.

```
byte[,,] array = new byte[XSize, YSize, ZSize];

int i = 0;

//other code

array[#,#,#] = cur;

//other code
```

I don't know how to get the correct numbers for the #,#,# from just i.

Comment: Which way do you want to loop through it?

Comment: Could you provide more information?  Are you trying to iterate over all items?  Or are you attempting to directly access a single element from a single lookup value?

Comment: My previous comment still holds:  Can you provide an input and the expected output?

Comment: I think you are trying to map (0,0,0) to 0, (0,0,1) to 1 and so on. Is that what you want? Could you clarify your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a 1d array to a 3d array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316278/convert-a-1d-array-to-a-3d-array)

Comment: @Lost Its better to improve previous question rather than posting new question.....

Comment: No it wouldn't let me delete it for 2 days.  I want to loop through it through z, y, then x.  So for example if the array was [4,4,4] then if 'i' was 2 then the index would be [0,0,2] or if i was 5 then it would be [0,1,1].  @James yes exactly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Supposing you want to iterate through Z, then Y, and then X. . .

```
int zDirection = i % zLength;
int yDirection = (i / zLength) % yLength;
int xDirection = i / (yLength * zLength);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to make an assumption about the orientation of the array-space. Assuming you are mapping the numbers with 0 corresponding to 0, 0, 0, and that you iterate z, then y, then x, the math is fairly simple:

```
int x;
int y;
int z;

if (i < XSize * YSize * ZSize)
{
    int zQuotient = Math.DivRem(i, ZSize, out z);
    int yQuotient = Math.DivRem(zQuotient, YSize, out y);
    x = yQuotient % XSize;
}
```

Note that this saves some redundant operations over BlackVegetable's solution. For a (3, 3, 3) matrix, this yields the set:

```
i (x, y, z)
0 (0, 0, 0)
1 (0, 0, 1)
2 (0, 0, 2)
3 (0, 1, 0)
4 (0, 1, 1)
5 (0, 1, 2)
6 (0, 2, 0)
7 (0, 2, 1)
8 (0, 2, 2)
9 (1, 0, 0)
10 (1, 0, 1)
11 (1, 0, 2)
12 (1, 1, 0)
13 (1, 1, 1)
14 (1, 1, 2)
15 (1, 2, 0)
16 (1, 2, 1)
17 (1, 2, 2)
18 (2, 0, 0)
19 (2, 0, 1)
20 (2, 0, 2)
21 (2, 1, 0)
22 (2, 1, 1)
23 (2, 1, 2)
24 (2, 2, 0)
25 (2, 2, 1)
26 (2, 2, 2)
```

Also, this is reversible with `i = z + y * ZSize + x * ZSize * YSize`.