# Convert Index of N*M*K array to N, M and K values?

Tags: arrays

Let's say I have a `3*3*3` **3D** array

If I have an element at location `[1,1,1]` of the array, I can find the index just by

```
1*3*3 + 1*3 + 1 == 13
```

But I need to *do the opposite*. I need to convert `13` into `[1,1,1]`. How do I do that?

Comment: `13 % 3 == 1` then `13 / 3 % 3 == 1` finally `13 / 3 / 3 == 1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a 1d index into a 3d index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845084/how-do-i-convert-a-1d-index-into-a-3d-index)

Comment: I dont want to use round functions

Comment: Why 3d? The problem is the same for 2d arrays, only simpler to grasp. Can you try figure out 2d first, and extrapolate from there?

Answer (score 1):

Use *modulo arithmetics*:

```
 13 / 3 / 3 == 1 // 1st index
 13 / 3 % 3 == 1 // 2nd index
 13 % 3 == 1     // 3d index
```

where `/` is *integer division* and `%` is *remainder*.

**Edit:** Let's generalize for

```
  # you have M = N = K = 3
 [M, N, K] array
```

and arbitrary `value` (`13` in your case)

```
  M-th index = value / K / N # % M can be dropped 
  N-th index = value / K % N
  K-th index = value % K
```

In case `mD` array

```
 [N1, N2, ..., Ni, ..., Nm]
```

we have

```
 i-th index = value / Nm / Nm-1 / ... / Ni+1 % Ni
```

Comment: sorry its not clear, i guess i used 3 everywhere. Can you tell me by the N M K notation please. And could you use brackets to indicate which operation comes first

Comment: This is, of course, correct, but I'm afraid it's just meaningless incantations for the OP, since he doesn't understand the _nature_ of what's happening here. (it he did, he'd be able to figure out this reverse transformation by himself). Some kind of visualisation might help, but producing a good one is hard work. :/